# React-Native library for image upload and cropping ?(supporting both android and ios)

Tags: android, ios, image, react-native

In my app i want to be able to upload an image from gallery or camera and be able to upload and set it in to an image view.Just like the feature in
Facebook,what app etc.

Suggest me a proper way to do it,a good library(a mostly used one)might be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are to many things still, here is the library for image select from gallary and camera,

https://github.com/react-community/react-native-image-picker

and here is the code to upload image using fetch.

```
    var photo = {
  uri: user.profilePicture,
  type: 'image/jpeg',
  name: 'photo.jpg',
};
var form = new FormData();
form.append("ProfilePicture", photo);
fetch(
  Constants.API_USER + 'me/profilePicture',
  {
    body: form,
    method: "PUT",
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + user.token
    }
  }
).then((response) => response.json())
.catch((error) => {
  alert("ERROR " + error)
})
.then((responseData) => {
  alert("Succes "+ responseData)
}).done();
```

Comment: what about the crop feature ?

Comment: harshal can you give me some reference code of a project in which you might have implemented this library ?

Comment: harshal, i used the crop library you suggested in the comment,i got a json response after i picked the image u got any idea how to append this to a react native image view.still a rookie in react native sorry.

Comment: what kind of respose you are getting? is it a url?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150147/discussion-between-amal-p-and-harshal-jadhav).